# What is wrong with my Recursive Binary-Search program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-search

I can't seem to figure out why my code keeps on returning **N** instead of **R**. I have tested what the letter would be before going to the return statement and as you can see in the image of the output, it should be **R**. Yet, it continues to return **N** as shown in the picture and I don't know why it would do that... I have tried hand-tracing the process and I still end up with R. I have included some notes within the code for you to see and understand my thoughts. I have also included a picture of the output at the bottom.

*Input: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']*

```
def binSearch(lst, what):
    position = ""
    original_lst = lst[:]
    if (position == what): # Doesn't do anything since no recursive is made when position is equal to R.
        return original_lst.index("%s" %position)
    else:
        midpoint = (len(lst))//2
        position = lst[midpoint]
        print("Looking at", position)
        if position > what:
            lst = lst[:midpoint]
            binSearch(lst, what)
        elif position < what:
            lst = lst[midpoint:]
            binSearch(lst, what)
        elif position == what: # Removable. Just Testing and seeing what position it results as.
            print("Position it ends up in:", position) # when I replace this later, I probably should use a binSearch(). I think?
        else:
            return -1 # this is for if the letter not found.
    return position # Why does it return N... instead of R? This originally was suppose to find the index of the letter on the list. I adjusted it to see what letter the program was searching for instead. It still results in the same problem if I change it to look for the index of letter instead as it looks for **N** instead of **R**
# just to clarify, I was aiming to use return original_lst.index("%s" %position) to find the index of the letter. I just changed it to see what letter its returning instead. 
    
    

lst = []
while True:
   val = input()
   if val == "exit":
      break
   lst.append(val)

print(lst)
lst.sort()
print(lst)

what = input("Enter element to search for:")
print(what)
where = binSearch(lst, what)
if where != -1: 
    print("Found at position", where)
else:
    print("Not found")
```

[Picture of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWIEJ.png)

Edit: This program was originally suppose to find the value of the letter. Position was suppose to be the letter and I would just return.index it at the end. However to make it more readable and easier to understand, I changed the return statement at the end. It still ends up with the same results of where it reutrns **N** instead of **R**.

Comment: Some thoughts:  ① How dare you name a variable `position` when in fact it doesn't hold a position.  It holds an element instead.  ② What is it good for to call `binSearch()` when you don't use its return value?  (You do this in the recursive calls.)  ③ You seem to search binary for the element, and as soon as you have found it, you use `.index()` to find its position.  `.index()` makes a linear search for the element.  So all your nice binary searching is useless.

Comment: Haha. Sorry about that. Position was suppose to use .index() to find its position in the list. However, to make it easier to understand, I changed it. I still am encountering the same problem if I change it to search index of element position as it gives me **N** instead of **R**.

Comment: What is your function supposed to return? Is it the element itself or its index in the list?

Comment: @PaulRooney The index of the list. However, I adjusted it to see what letter it is returning instead. It still results in the same problem if I look for the index instead as it searchs for the index of **N** instead of **R**

Comment: @Alfe As for the second part, I'm sorry. I don't understand. What do you mean by linear search? Is that the source of my problem?

Comment: @HiDanny the benefit of binary search is that it searches in logarithmic time (i.e. it cuts the field in half on each iteration). Index is a function that just iterates over the entire list, it is linear and thus defeats the object of your binary search. It is not the source of your issue, but it will hamper the performance of your binary search, effectively making it not a binary search. Look [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/bisect.py) for the python standard library implementation of bisect, which is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to put that.  Too many flaws in this source to have  a feeling that answering your question will do any help.  Some flaws I mentioned above.  The main point is that binary searching is meant to be performant.  That rules out creating sub-arrays or using any linear search in the process.  Also, the `binSearch()` should receive a list and two boundary-indexes to search in and return the index where it found something.  Maybe you should rethink your whole approach.  (Or maybe I'm just to stupid or stubborn to understand the genius in yours.)

Comment: @PaulRooney Oh... I didn't realize Index function did that... I will have revisit in making it into a proper binary search. However, I'm still curious about the problem I'm experiencing. Do you know why it would return N instead of R?

Comment: @Alfe I just started python, so I'm probably just making a lot of errors. Sorry about that. It seems as though that this isn't a proper binary-search as pointed out by Paul Rooney. However, I still am curious about why it would return N instead of R. Do you have any idea?

Comment: like @Alfe said you are ignoring the return value of the recursive calls. This is undoubtedly an issue.

Comment: Copying the array for each recursion is not a good idea. Also, you should return the position of the item in the original item if found, or -1 or something if not found. An example you may find here: https://gist.github.com/nipuntalukdar/238f2977238284b71332b512fe26e39b

Comment: @HiDanny Don't get me wrong, you don't have to apologize for lacking knowledge.  I just wanted to point out why I think answering your question won't help a lot (besides being rather complex).  It's like answering why the seats of a cabriolet get wet when you drive into a lake.  I propose to consider rewriting your binary search in the manner I sketched in my comment above.  You will probably run into completely other problems then, but at least the approach is sound, so asking here again will make more sense.  If you notice that your ride a dead horse, dismount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call the algorithm, **N** is in the middle of the array. So this line

```
position = lst[midpoint]
```

sets `position` to **N**. Then, you ***never change the value*** of `position`!

You should change the two recursive lines to:

```
return binSearch(lst, what)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the syntax

```
return position
```

Here is what i got

```
def binSearch(lst, what,low=0, high=None):
  high = len(lst) if high is None else high
  pos = int(low + (high-low)/len(lst))
  if (pos==len(lst)):
    return False
  elif (lst[pos]==what):
    return pos
  elif high==low:
    return False
  elif (lst[pos]<what):
    return binSearch(lst, what, pos + 1, high)
  else:
    assert lst[pos] > what
    return binSearch(lst, what, low, pos)

lst = []
while True:
   val = input()
   if val == "exit":
      break
   lst.append(val)

print(lst)
lst.sort()
print(lst)

what = input("Enter element to search for:")
print(what)
where = binSearch(lst, what)
if where != -1: 
    print("Found at position", where+1) #+1 because the index start from 0
    print (lst[where])
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I should have specified that the def binSearch(lst, what) couldn't be changed as it was the template that my professor gave me. However, it seems that your code is an actual binary search unlike mine. Thanks for showing how to do make an actual binary-search!!

Comment: Sorry if this was not the one you need. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The first time through you are going to hit this line of code:
`position = lst[midpoint]`
and thus set position to 'N'.
Then you recurse through the search, but at each branch you execute:
`binSearch(lst, what)`. The 'position' variable in this new, inner binSearch call will in no way affect the position in the outer call. If you want to write the function in this way then that line should really be something like: `position = binSearch(lst, what)`. That should then update the position in the outer call correctly.